# Why am I seeing smtp.gmail.com:cabbellgroup (offline) under Outgoing mail server?

Tags: email

My emails are not getting through to anyone.  When I go to MAIL and then to
ACCOUNTS and then at the bottom under OUTGOING MAIL SERVER (SMTP) it shows that the server is offline.  Is this the reason my emails are not getting through?  What can I do about it?

Comment: Did it ever work?

Comment: Do you use a firewall? Which ports are being used? It should be set to either 465 or 587. Also, the outgoing server should only be smtp.gmail.com. I‘m not quit sure why yours has :cabbellgroup attached to it. Is it a private account or is it associated with any firm/organsisarion? Maybe try to remove that and see if it works.